# how to redirect session login url in moodle

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

Moodle normally redirect to login page when session **Timeout**.

Is there any option to **redirect** another page url instead of going to

```
$CFG->wwwroot.'/login/index.php'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default login page by setting `$CFG->alternateloginurl` via the admin interface at `/admin/settings.php?section=manageauths`. Any redirects requiring user login will then automatically point to your custom location instead.

Comment: awesome the solutions  works :) , Is it possible to assign the redirection only for admin ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that isn't possible because at the time of the redirection the user isn't logged in yet, so Moodle would have no way of knowing whether it was the admin or someone else about to log in.

Comment: If the admin would always be accessing from the same IP address (and no other user would ever use that address) then you may be able to do it by adding an extra condition to the line `if (!empty($CFG->alternateloginurl)) {` in login/index.php (line 265 on the master branch at https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/login/index.php).

Answer (score 4):

Yes by using **`redirect()`** function, you can redirect from one page to another page in moodle.

**Example**

```
$urltogo= $CFG->wwwroot.'/dashboard/';
redirect($urltogo);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the index.php i.e the home page use the function require_login()

The require_login() function will automatically redirect the home page to the login page.

Note: make sure you use the require_login() function below the require_once('config.php')